# removing objects from an array

Tags: c++, arrays, destructor

I am creating a program that uses an array of objects declared with

```
Element * elements = new Element[number];
```

where an element is a `class` that has/needs a its own destructor.

when I go to delete this would I use just use array delete, and have the program worry about calling the destructor:

```
delete [] elements;
```

or do I call the destructor for each item explicitly with keyword delete:

```
for(int ii = 0; ii< ArraySize; ii++)
    delete elements[ii];
delete [] elements;
```

Note: I understand that I could probably use something like `boost::ptr_vector`, but I wanted similar to `hashTable` functionality (so the for loop would need additional information, but that is outside of the direct scope of this question) which is why I am using a traditional array. I would still like to know which behavior is needed to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: You're not storing pointers in your array, so `delete[]` should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one. You should

```
delete [] elements;
```

The second one is incorrect and should give you errors if you try to compile it.

Comment: though the object in the array will need the destructor called, and so basically just deleting the array will call the destructor for each object

Comment: Yes, `delete [] elements` will free the memory for the entire array and call the destructor for each object. You `delete` what you `new`, and `delete []` what you `new []`. Here, you only did `new []`, so you only need `delete []`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `delete [] elements;` should be sufficient.

You'd use your second piece of code with something like:

```
Element **elements;

elements = new Element *[rows];
for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
    elements[i] = new Element;
```

This combination rarely makes much sense though. To make at least some sense, each row would itself be a dynamically allocated array as well:

```
elements = new Element *[rows];
for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
    elements[i] = new Element[row_len];
```

In this case, your deletion would look something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
    delete [] elements[i];
delete [] elements;
```

As you're doing it right now, however, none of what you've said really justifies home-rolled dynamic allocation at all. `std::vector<Element> elements(number);` would work perfectly well.

Comment: I am wanting a hash table functionality that actually beats out even `std::vector` in terms of operations `HashTable` is approximately O(2) even for large tables assuming less then 75% full, while even the most well implemented vector/contiguous list is O(n), and this array is expected to handle a large number of objects.

Comment: @gardian06: But what you're doing right now is creating a contiguous array, just like `std::vector` would. To implement a hash table, you probably want `std::vector<Element *>` instead. Of course, for a hash table, your first choice should normally be `std::unordered_map<Element>`.